# WinXP: How do I allow read-only remote desktop to non-admin users?

Tags: windows-xp, terminal-services

Using (WinXP flavored) Server 2003, how do I allow read-only remote desktop to non-admin users?   I don't want to use the "invite for Remote Assistance" feature of MSN Live Messenger.   I would rather have a method that doesnt require the chat program and instead ONLY requires the terminal services client program.

I can't seem to find the configuration setting anywhere.

I believe there is a way to get a admin session (session id =0)  to prompt for a read-only non-interactive session but I don't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about viewing your current active session, I have yet to find a good way using built in Windows components.

The best I have found is simply to install a flavour of VNC, such as [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) then they can connect either through a VNC viewer or the webpage. It is quite flexible and you can allow view only - in to your current active session.

Answer (score 1):

[Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx) is based of UltraVNC, but offers a much more easier to use interface and does not require port forwarding.

It also does the presentation mode you're looking for.

Comment: How does this compare to WebEx.  It looks similar...

Comment: WebEx gives you full audio video conferencing, along with a dialin solution for people on slow connections. If you're just looking to share your screen, Teamviewer will give you the features you're looking for without the cost for the features you may not need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to use RDC in view-only mode, unless you write yourself a program incorporating the RDC ActiveX object. I believe some such projects may be found around the web, but it's a heck of a job. So I think that you really need to look at third-party products.

This article [6 free remote desktop sharing and screen sharing solutions](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/cool-websites/5-free-remote-desktop-sharing-and-screen-sharing-solutions/) describes six quite interesting solutions. One of them night suite your needs.

Another solution is to use the new screen-sharing option now incorporated into Skype [Screen sharing](http://www.skype.com/allfeatures/screensharing/). It's certainly quite interesting to continue talking via Skype while you share your screen.

Comment: Very helpful post.  I'll give an up-point for that.  I might not choose as the answer though.